# Build and run button disable in Unity configuration

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am new in Unity. I need to build sample android project, I made everything according to this tutorial

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/06/creating-an-android-java-plugin-for-unity3d/

But on final step when I need to choose android as a platform I faced that `Build and run` button disable

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to 'Switch Platform' the button beside it first. Also just make sure you installed the corresponding Android bundle for the Unity Version you are using in Unity Hub.